# Some More Fun with a Circular Table - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

There are $n$ people seated on a circular table which has seats numbered from 1 to $n$ clockwise. Let $k$ be a fixed integer, between $2$ and $n$ (both inclusive).

The people can change their seats. There are two types of moves permitted:

1. Each person moves to the next seat clockwise.
2. Only the ones in seats $1$ and $k$ exchange their seats.

Determine, as a function of $n$ and $k$, the number of possible configurations of people in the table that can be attained by using a sequence of permitted moves.

My thoughts:

If condition (2) is not there then answer is obviously $n$; but if (2) is imposed on each arrangement of (1), then, you can further rotate that particular arrangement $n$ times to get new arrangements. I'm not sure how to get the closed form of $f(n,k)$.

For small values of $n$, such as 3, 4, etc. it is easy to calculate by manual counting; but for larger values it's becoming a difficult task. Also, I think this could maybe be a problem involving some combinatorial recursion.

Comment: What is the number of permitted moves I mean can only 2 or only 3 or only 4, etc people can exchange their seats

Comment: There is no limit given for permitted moves, as far as I can understand. Do they want to us consider all possible arrangements? (ones that can be achieved through permitted moves, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operations as given in the question have a fixed swapper of two persons and a moving table (the "table" being the circle of people). Now let the *swapper* move and fix the *table*; we lose only a position factor in this (which will be reintroduced later).

Sliding the swapper around the table, we see that the people split into $\gcd(n,k-1)$ disjoint cycles of $\frac n{\gcd(n,k-1)}$ people each (here illustrated for $n=18,k=5$):

[image]

Within each cycle, because we can swap any two people who are adjacent in the cycle, we can achieve any permutation – $\left(\frac n{\gcd(n,k-1)}\right)!$ ways. Since we have $\gcd(n,k-1)$ independent cycles, we can achieve $\left(\left(\frac n{\gcd(n,k-1)}\right)!\right)^{\gcd(n,k-1)}$ arrangements with the modified operations.

However, the original operations allow us to move the $\gcd(n,k-1)$ cycles around the circle, which the modified operations do not allow. Since any cycle can occupy a fixed position on the circle, there are $\gcd(n,k-1)$ distinct ways to align the cycles to the circle, the missing position factor from before. Finally
$$f(n,k)=\gcd(n,k-1)\left(\left(\frac n{\gcd(n,k-1)}\right)!\right)^{\gcd(n,k-1)}$$

Comment: Umm, your solution does seem to 'work' for all the cases I've tried till now, but I'm not able to figure out how you got the general case; how did you think of what you did - could you please be a little more detailed with the explanation at each step? I'd appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @schrodinger_16 done.

Comment: Great. Understood it now! One last thing, is the part about people splitting into exactly gcd(n,k-1) disjoint cycles based only on observation?

Comment: @schrodinger_16 the answer to that is partly based on modular arithmetic. We swap 1 and $k$, who are $k-1$ apart from each other; the cycles arise because the smallest solution $m$ to $(k-1)m\equiv0\bmod n$ is a factor of $n$, which may not be $n$ itself. Indeed, $m=\frac n{\gcd(n,k-1)}$.

Comment: (+1) deserves more upvotes, I feel. Very slick!